# Replace Font in PDF

Tags: pdf, embedded-fonts

is it possible to replace a (embedded) font in a pdf-file? I tried Acrobat, but there I just can replace paragraph by paragraph. I want to replace every word with that font in the complete document.

Maybe possible with ghostscript or anything like that?

Comment: There's probably a plug-in for Acrobat for that, but your replacement font will need to have the same metrics as the original one (i.e. it should be easy to replace one Times with another variant of Times).

Comment: Hm yes, I didn't consider this. It looks very ugly to replace centered text ;)
But thank you anyway!

Comment: It cannot be done as the paragraphs within the PDF-file are not continuous and fluid. You will never get correct margins, kerning or word-wrapping. If the PDF-file is encoded with PDF 1.7, you may be able to open them in Illustrator and replace it there. But only page by page.

Answer (score 2):

Infix Pro can do it

http://www.iceni.com/infixDownload.htm?b=3

http://www.iceni.com/blog/how-to-change-a-pdf-font-quickly/

Edit -> Find & Replace -> Replace Font